# accordion group.isOpen is not working

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to collapse accordion on page load for that i am using is-open="group.isOpen" but it is not working.

Code:

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group  is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="session in sessions.list" >
    <accordion-heading>
     <span>{{session.title}} : </span>
     <span>{{session.scheduled_date | date:'uvarsityDate'}}</span>
     <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
     ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
   </accordion-heading>
   <div class="">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <dl class="dl-horizontal list-group-item">
          <dt>About the class</dt>
          <dd ng-bind-html='session.description'></dd>
       </dl>
       <dl class="dl-horizontal list-group-item">
          <dt>Timings</dt>
          <dd>{{session.time_from}} to {{session.time_to}}</dd>
          <span></span>  
       </dl> 
     </ul>             
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
```

Could any one suggest me how to make accordion in open state on page load?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `"group.isOpen"` in your `<accordion-group>` but `"isopen"` variable for your `glyphicon-chevron`. You should be using the same variable name.

It should look like this:

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group  is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="session in sessions.list" >
    <accordion-heading>
     <span>{{session.title}} : </span>
     <span>{{session.scheduled_date | date:'uvarsityDate'}}</span>
     <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
     ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.isOpen}"></i>
   </accordion-heading>
   <div class="">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <dl class="dl-horizontal list-group-item">
          <dt>About the class</dt>
          <dd ng-bind-html='session.description'></dd>
       </dl>
       <dl class="dl-horizontal list-group-item">
          <dt>Timings</dt>
          <dd>{{session.time_from}} to {{session.time_to}}</dd>
          <span></span>  
       </dl> 
     </ul>             
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `session` variable in `ng-repeat` to store the `isOpen` state.

```
<accordion-group is-open="session.isOpen" ng-repeat="session in sessions.list">
```

And set the `isOpen` to true at the session you want it to be opened in a controller:

```
$scope.sessions = {
  list: [
    {
      title: 'foo',
      description: 'fooooo',
      time_from: new Date(),
      time_to: new Date(),
      isOpen: false,
    },
    {
      title: 'bar',
      description: 'barrrr',
      time_from: new Date(),
      time_to: new Date(),
      isOpen: true,           // this session will be opened.
    },
    {
      title: 'baz',
      description: 'bazzzz',
      time_from: new Date(),
      time_to: new Date(),
      isOpen: false,
    },
  ]
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/10JZ4ZhD20KV0p8wozyb?p=preview